# Problems with scrolling in HorizontalListView(android)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

I use a `HorizontalListView` to scroll I use the code below (method setOnItemClickListener)

```
 listview.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int centerX = listview.getChildAt(position).getLeft();

                    listview.scrollTo(centerX);
                }
            });
```

but there is a problem when position reaches `3` or more , then I get an error:

```
12-28 01:33:37.814  20841-20841/com.example.SmsService E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.SmsService, PID: 20841
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.SmsService.VideoView$1$1.run(VideoView.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think that probably because I use **looped listView**:

```
  @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;//
    }
```

**how I could fix this problem?** And maybe there are other ways scroll listView? (Scrolling Smooth does not work ) [My Class.](https://gist.github.com/diha-o/c004352966f07bd02614) And .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/ll">
    <VideoView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/videoView"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                    android:id="@+id/listview2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                    android:id="@+id/listview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                    android:clickable="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How many items you have in the horizontal scroll view? And which one is line 68 in `ViedoView.java`?

Comment: @Rohit5k2,If you mean how much can be seen on the screen, 3-4.

Comment: @Rohit5k2, "And which one is line 68 in ViedoView.java?" - its - "int centerX = listview.getChildAt(position).getLeft();"

Comment: No. total number of items??

Comment: @Rohit5k2, it looped ListView number is probably "Integer.MAX_VALUE", but can you ask about it 'private static String [] dataObjects = new String [] {"Text # 1"
            "Text # 2"
            "Text # 3 ", "Text # 4 ", "Text # 5" } ; '

Comment: @Rohit5k2, and sorry for my English Language.

Comment: Its better if you post your complete class here.

Comment: @Rohit5k2, get https://gist.github.com/diha-o/c004352966f07bd02614

Comment: @Rohit5k2, have eny ideas?

Comment: Probably you are trying to get view that is not visible that's why you are getting null pointer error. You can see my answer to prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
public void run() {
    int centerX = listview.getChildAt(position).getLeft();
    listview.scrollTo(centerX)
}
```

to

```
public void run() {
    View v = listView.getChildAt(position);
    if(v != null)
    {
        int centerX = v.getLeft();
        listview.scrollTo(centerX);
    }
}
```

You might have to find another way to move your items. This code will only fix the null pointer exception.

Comment: Yes , I understand , but I do not understand why if position = 3  I get an error , because in my "listView-> child" has  positions number 3?

Comment: You might have to review your complete code once again. I am not able to see it right now.

Comment: Well, how then can the transition to the next "child" in "Listview" to scroll on the screen center?